# How to import logger module in src and use it on all groovy scripts?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am newbie to groovy/pipeline, I put this in `vars/build.groovy` to check if project and branch are passed in in order to call build function.

How to convert the below `println` line into logger? what modules should I import? or can I have this defined somewhere in `src/`, so it can be used on all `vars/*` groovy scripts, instead of importing the logger module on all vars/ scripts?

I need to use logger, so it will have option to print where the error is coming from, e.g: in this case the error is from `build.groovy`

```
def call(Map args) {
    // Check if args has project and branch.
    if (!args.containsKey('project') || !args.containsKey('branch') ) {
        println "project and branch are mandatory arguments"
        //looking to use something like: log.error("project and branch are mandatory arguments")
        return 1
    }
    // project and branch passed-in, do rest of the steps.
    // ...
```

I call this from JenkinsFile as below:

```
//...
stage('Run build')
{
     steps {
        build([project:'path/of/project', branch:"foo"])
     }
//...
```